# How to handle chained promises

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularfire

I'm a little bit confused how should I handle the promises in my situation.

This is my factory:

```
return {
  getCategory: function(categoryId) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('categories').child(categoryId);
    var category = $firebaseObject(ref);
    return category.$loaded().then(function() {
        return category;
    });
  },
  getEntry: function(categoryId, entryId) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('entries').child(categoryId).child(entryId);
    var entry = $firebaseObject(ref);
    return entry.$loaded().then(function() {
        return entry;
    });
  }
}
```

In my factory I try to avoid doing like this:

```
var d = $q.defer();
if() {
    d.resolve();
}
return d.promise;
```

Because the $loaded() returns a promise itself.

And this is my controller:

```
var categoryId = 'abc';
var entryId = 'def';
// so here i'm getting the category
MyFactory.getCategory(categoryId)
.then(function(category) {
    if(category.$value === null)
    {
        $scope.error = 'The category does not exist';
    }
    else if(new Date() > new Date(category.expireDate))
    {
        $scope.error = 'The category has expired';
    }
    else {
        $scope.category = category;
        // if no errors
        return MyFactory.getEntry(category.$id, entryId);
    }
})
.then(function(entry) {
    if(entry.$value === null)
    {
        $scope.error = 'No such entry';
    }
    else {
        $scope.entry = entry;
    }
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

What I want to achieve is to get the category first, and then whether there are some errors or not, get the entry respectively. The data is coming from a Firebase database.

This is kind of working, however I'm not really sure how should I handle the promise when I want to do a next .then and **don't nest them one in the other like this:**

```
MyFactory.getCategory().then(function(category) {
    if(no category errors) {
        MyFactory.getEntry().then(function() {
            // ...
        });
    }
});
```

For now I'm getting an error in the console (it's type error entry undefined) when for example the category expired or does not exist.
I think I did something wrong in the controller when I return but I'm not really sure and hope you can help me dispel all doubts.

So the real question is how should I handle this **correctly**, to work as expected?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a rejected promise when there is an error.

Look at the following example:

```
MyFactory
    .getCategory(categoryId)
    .then(function (category) {
        if (category.$value === null) {
            return $q.reject('The category does not exist');
        }
        if (new Date() > new Date(category.expireDate)) {
            return $q.reject('The category has expired');
        }
        $scope.category = category;
        return MyFactory.getEntry(category.$id, entryId);
    })
    .then(function (entry) {
        if (entry.$value === null) {
            return $q.reject('No such entry');
        }
        $scope.entry = entry;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        $scope.error = error;
    });
```

Do not forget to inject `$q` to your controller.

**Edit**

I would also suggest you move the "error logic" to your service, so the controller would always received either data in `.then(data => { ... })` or an error string in `.catch(error => { ... })`. This would make your controllers cleaner and if you use those service method in a different controller, you would not have to replicate your logic there as well.

**Service**

```
return {
    getCategory: function(categoryId) {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('categories').child(categoryId);
        var category = $firebaseObject(ref);
        return category.$loaded().then(function() {
            if (category.$value === null) {
                return $q.reject('The category does not exist');
            }
            if (new Date() > new Date(category.expireDate)) {
                return $q.reject('The category has expired');
            }
            return category;
        });
    },
    getEntry: function(categoryId, entryId) {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('entries').child(categoryId).child(entryId);
        var entry = $firebaseObject(ref);
        return entry.$loaded().then(function() {
            if (entry.$value === null) {
                return $q.reject('No such entry');
            }
            return entry;
        });
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
MyFactory
    .getCategory(categoryId)
    .then(function (category) {
        $scope.category = category;
        return MyFactory.getEntry(category.$id, entryId);
    })
    .then(function (entry) {
        $scope.entry = entry;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        $scope.error = error;
    });
```

Comment: Oh gosh! That helped me alot. Thank you.
But a little confusion again. You are using $q.reject in the service. Which promise is it actually rejecting? Since you don't do $q.defer()?

Comment: I am glad I could help!. `$q.reject()` is a "shortcut" which creates and rejects a promise in one step. Here is the official documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject